# Is there any distribution that only takes value 0 and 10, both have 1/2 probability?

Tags: distributions, bernoulli-distribution

Now I want to generate random numbers. It has 1/2 probability generating 0 and 1/2 probability generating 10. So what the distribution of the numbers is? It looks like Bernoulli but it isn't. (Bernoulli only takes 0 and 1, rather than 0 and 10).

Answer (score 8):

Not all possible probability distributions have names, and you do not *need* to refer to your distribution by a specific name.

I would simply call what you have a "scaled Bernoulli distribution". Or simply a "two-point distribution on $0$ and $10$ with equal probabilities" - after all, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) says that the Bernoulli "is also a special case of the **two-point distribution**, for which the possible outcomes need not be 0 and 1."